# What happens when you use arithmetic operators inside of a string declaration?

Tags: java, string, math

If there is an arithmetic operator inside of a string declaration, how does the String treat the operator?
For example in this case:

```
String s = "de32";
s = s.charAt(0) * 2 + "";   
System.out.println(s);
```

String s is not `dd` but instead is `102`. What is the `* 2` mean for the string?

Answer (score 4):

`s.charAt(0)` is a `char` ('d'), and `char` is a numeric type. The numeric value of the character `'d'` is `100`. Therefore `s.charAt(0) * 2` simply multiplies that value by `2`, which results in `200` (not `102` as you wrote).

Then the result is converted to a `String`, since you appended to it an empty `String`, so `s` is assigned `"200"`.

The expression is evaluated left to right, so it is equivalent to:

```
s = (s.charAt(0) * 2) + "";
```

- First the `char` 'd' is promoted to an `int` and multiplied by `2`.
- Then the resulting `int` (200) is appended to the empty `String` "". resulting in the `String` "200".

Comment: @AndyTurner sure

Answer (score 0):

At 0 position char d is there and it is multiplied with 2. So ASCII value of d is multiplied by 2. Since ASCII value of d is 100 so it gives result 200. Then it is appended to empty string and give "200" as a string .